# Storing an array from pre-defined set in a database field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, database, activerecord

I have a model which looks like this

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  serialize :languages_spoken, Array
  ...
end
```

For the domain of the application it only matters whether an user speaks languages from a pre-defined set of `English, Spanish, German, French or Italian`

Currently I am passing an array in params chosen from a multiselect in the view which is eventually serialized. However, I want to search the users by languages they speak and searching in serialized fields is pretty clumsy in ActiveRecord.

I've tried creating a different model for **Language** with many-to-many relationship via join table but I think it's an overkill for such a small feature.

I have also thought of using **Postgres array** though I don't want to be dependent on Postgres.

Enum field would be great but it naturally only works with one value.

Is there any elegant yet simple solution for this problem ? Thank you.

Comment: MySQL has a [SET type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html), but I think it's unsupported by Rails. And you would have just another dependency.

Comment: Whether you are certain that the language set is limited to “English, Spanish, German, French or Italian” and won’t grow with time, I would go with 5 boolean fields in the database for each language respectively. Another possibility would be to just serialize country iso codes as `join(',')` and match against `%q|language LIKE "%#{lang}%"|`.

Comment: Not posting this as an answer as it needs to more explanation, but it sounds like you need a bit field. I use this gem to make it slightly easier: https://github.com/pboling/flag_shih_tzu

Comment: @DickieBoy very interesting. Thanks for a tip!

Comment: @peter if that turns out to be what you are looking for i will post a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** My bad, I forgot about the key part of the question. It has to be a many-to-many kind of relation. with `enum` you can't do that. Rails stores the values as integers in the DB. So, it only stores one value.

If you are willing to add a Postgres dependency, you can use `hstore` type. It is also supported by Rails 4.

### Original Answer

If you are on Rails 4.1 or later, you can use [Active Record enums](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#active-record-enums).

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum languages_spoken: [:english, :spanish, :german, :french, :italian]
end


profile.english? # => true/false
profile.languages_spoken  # => "english"

Profile.english # => Relation for all "english" profiles
Profile.languages_spoken # => { "English" => 0, "Spanish" => 1, "etc" => ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to store multiple values in an enum field ? Meaning that an user speaks two or more languages. If so, how would I go about it ?

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot about the key part of your question. It has to be many-to-many kind of relation. My bad! No, with `enum` Rails stores your values as integers in the database. So you can't store multiple values.